# Lucene:Using RAMDictionary for spellchecker not seems like working

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net, spell-checking

I want to index my spellchecker using directory as RAMDirectory istead of using FSDirectory. Since I have already created the index I just want to use that user index to index spellchecker but I am not getting any suggestions.`exist` also return 0 so i am guessing index is not getting created properly.

```
try{

        StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory,config);

        JSONArray documentArray = new JSONArray();
        String[] fieldArray = {"field"};
        JSONObject documentObj= new JSONObject();
        documentObj.put("field", "KARNATAKA");

        documentArray.put(documentObj);

        JSONObject documentObj1= new JSONObject();
        documentObj1.put("field", "KERALA");

        documentArray.put(documentObj1);

        for (int i = 0; i < documentArray.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject docObj = documentArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Document doc = new Document();
            for (int j = 0; j < fieldArray.length; j++)
            {
              doc.add(new Field(fieldArray[j], docObj.getString(fieldArray[j]), org.apache.lucene.document.TextField.TYPE_STORED));
            }
            indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
          }


        indexWriter.commit();
        indexWriter.close();


        DirectoryReader ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        SpellChecker spellChecker = new SpellChecker(directory);
        spellChecker.clearIndex();

        spellChecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(ireader, "field"), new IndexWriterConfig(new StandardAnalyzer()),true);

        String[] suggestions = spellChecker.suggestSimilar("KANATAKA", 5);

        System.out.println(spellChecker.exist("Karnataka".toUpperCase()));
        if(suggestions.length > 0 )
            System.out.println(suggestions[0]);
        spellChecker.close();




    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help what I might be doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`SpellChecker.clearIndex()`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/contrib-spellchecker/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html#clearIndex()) says:

> Removes all terms from the spell check index.

I doesn't look like that is what you want to do. I'd remove that line, or probably better yet, just use a new directory for the spellchecker index, instead of using the same one as the source index.

Comment: using a dedicated index for the spellchecker is recommended